# Why are my Javascript keyboard inputs not working for my Phaser sprite?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a game with Phaser and I tried using the usual keyboard inputs that you would usually use for Phaser, but they didn't get my sprite moving. Here is my phaser code(without the phaser keyboard inputs):

```html
const gameState = {};
        
    const config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 850,
        height: 650,
        backgroundColor: 0xa362d1,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 200 },
                enableBody: true,
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload, 
            create, 
            update
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
  
        
    function preload (){
        this.load.image('boy', 'boy.png')
    }

    function create(){
        gameState.boy = this.add.sprite(400, 550, 'boy').setScale(0.75)
       
    }
        
    function update (){
        
        
     }
```

I am trying to get my sprite to move using the keyboard inputs anyway, so I tried using plain old javascript to get the job done. Here is my javascript code:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpHandler, false);

var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false; 
var downPressed = false;

function keyDownHandler(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 39){
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 37){
        leftPressed = true;
    }
    
    if (event.keyCode == 40){
        downPressed = true;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 38){
        upPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 39){
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 37){
        leftPressed = false;
    }
    
    if (event.keyCode == 40){
        downPressed = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 38){
        upPressed = false;
    }
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if(rightPressed){
        playerX += 5;
    }
    else if(leftPressed) {
        playerX -= 5;
    }
    if(downPressed) {
        playerY += 5;
    }
    else if(upPressed) {
        playerY -= 5;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img, playerX, playerY);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    
}
```

And yet, still no results. I was wondering if there was some type of problem with my code or if maybe I had some type of syntax issue. Thanks again stack community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you would create a keyUp and a keyDown function to see if the keys was pressed or not, but if i may suggest a different approach.

First, create an object with the keys you want in your game, for example :

```
this.keys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
            w: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W,
            s: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S,
            a: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A,
            d: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D
        });
```

Second, you can create a function to watch those keys, like so :

```
function handleMoving() {
        if (this.keys.w.isDown // Or this.keys.w.isUp) {
            
            player.body.setVelocityX(160); // Whatever you want

        } 
        
        else if (this.keys.s.isDown) {
            
            player.body.setVelocityX(-160); // Whatever you want

        } 

// ... and so on
        
}
```

and then don't forget to call the function `handleMoving()` in the `update()` .